# How to repeat <option> tags in Polymer 2.x?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

In Polymer 1.0 I'd repeat the `<option>` tags inside the `<select>` tag like this:

```html
<select>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
    <option value$="[[item]]">[[item]]</option>
  </template>
</select>
```

But in Polymer 2.x it's recommended to use the `<dom-repeat>` tag:

```html
<select>
  <dom-repeat items="{{items}}">
    <template>
      <option value$="[[item]]">[[item]]</option>
    </template>
  </dom-repeat>
</select>
```

But this does not work. So how to repeat `<option>` tags in Polymer 2?

Comment: since the dom-repeat element is not fully completed and has many reported bugs it is propably better to work with is="dom-repeat". you can propably post this on github as issue, but i am not sure, if it is bug. There have to be some workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue looks similar to the [one reported for `<dom-repeat>` inside `<table>`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4135).

The workaround for now is to use "hybrid mode", where the 2.0 `<dom-repeat>` wraps a `<template is="dom-repeat">`:

```
<select>
  <dom-repeat items="[[items]]">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
      <option value="[[item]]">[[item]]</option>
    </template>
  </dom-repeat>
</select>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/XpoVMB)

**UPDATE:** @DocDude (Arthur Evans from the Polymer team) [noted in Slack](https://polymer.slack.com/archives/2-0-preview/p1487700822003007) that using `<template is="dom-repeat">` will still be supported **inside a Polymer 2.0 element**. You only need to use the `element` wrapper from outside the element (e.g., in `index.html`).

[image: slack discussion]

@KevinShaaf from the Polymer core team has also [confirmed this in GitHub](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4135#issuecomment-282441565):

[image: github comment]

Comment: The [Polymer 2.0 About page](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#type-extension) states that "Apple has said it will not implement `is`, we will not be encouraging its use to avoid indefinite reliance on the custom elements polyfill". So I think this probably is the short-term correct way to do this (I'm accepting this as the correct answer), but I hope there will be some more standards-compilant way to do this in the future.

Comment: @jehna1 That's true that Apple won't support `is` *natively*, but the polyfills will continue to support it in the meantime (while the bug in `<dom-repeat>` is being worked on). The 2.0 code that you originally questioned is indeed standards-compliant, so that will work after the bugfix lands.